# How to buy Impervious Toughness?

Tags: powers, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

Impervious Toughness seems to be a common case in M&Ms to represent characters with great resistance to damage. But how do you buy Impervious for Toughness? Impervious is an Extra with +1/rank cost, but you cannot buy ranks of Toughness, only increase it by buying ranks for your Stamina or the Protection power.

Where do I add that +1/rank cost? To my stamina cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't access my 3E book to see if they restated it, but [from the 2E FAQ](https://freeronin.com/2e_files/MM2eFAQ.pdf):

> **Some archetypes have “Impervious Toughness,” where is this power found?**
> See the Protection power on page 96, in particular the description of the Impervious extra. It can specifically be applied
> to the Toughness save as well, which is the case with those archetypes

So yes, you essentially are adding it to your Stamina cost, although the way it's offset in the power section makes it more of an Enhanced Trait which is able to be Nullified and might have its own descriptor (for example, I had one Powerhouse build who naturally had 12 Stamina, but his Impervious Toughness had a magic descriptor).

Comment: But how do I apply the costs from Impervious to Toughness? I can't buy Toughness ranks. How do I add the cost to something I cannot buy? Do I just need to multiply the ranks of Toughness with the cost of Impervious (1 point)? An Impervious Toughness 8 would cost 8 points?

Comment: Yes, you basically treat your Toughness from Stamina as if it were Protection, making it 8 PP to add Impervious to your Toughness 8 (presumably bought via Stamina, although Defensive Roll would also be an option).

Answer (score 5):

#### You add it to whatever is increasing your Protection.

Each rank of Impervious Protection costs one point. If you have a Stamina of 4, a Protection of 8, and eight points of Impervious Protection, you'd be spending 24 points on it altogether. Similarly, you could have Stamina 0, Protection 12, and make some or all of those ranks of Protection Impervious for one point each - though with Stamina 0 you couldn't make any of your ranks of Stamina Impervious,  since you don't have any

Comment: In your case, you are adding Impervious to Protection power. Protection cost 1/rank. With Impervious, it goes to 2/rank. So, 8 ranks times 2/rank equals 16 points. How are you making this math? I'm not getting the same result. Can you please edit your answer with more details? More, my question is regarding Impervious Toughness. There are characters without Protection power with Impervious Toughness, like Paragon archetype in DC Adventures book.

Comment: @BrunoEstrazulas In the case I included, it was 4 ranks of Stamina (8 points), 8 ranks of Protection (8 points), and 8 ranks of Impervious (8 points).